# PHP array_multisort accented characters

Tags: php

I'm trying to use array_multisort to sort items in array by strings which can contain accented characters (czech language).

I found some tips on using setlocale and array_multisort with SORT_LOCALE_STRING flag, but it is not working.

Any chance to get a working example of array_multisort with SORT_LOCALE_STRING flag?

Here is my code snippet:

```
$oldLocale = setlocale( LC_ALL, "0" );
setlocale( LC_ALL, 'cs_CZ.utf8' );
array_multisort( $accented_string, SORT_ASC, SORT_LOCALE_STRING, $my_array );
setlocale( LC_ALL, $oldLocale );`
```

Here is an example:

I have a multidimensional array, I'm sorting it by names of the czech cities.

**Some czech cities are:** Praha, Beroun, Plzeň, České Budějovice, Liberec. If I sort it just by plain array_multidimensional sorting, **the results is:**
Beroun, Liberec, Plzeň, Praha, České Budějovice.

**I need to get here:** 
Beroun, České Budějovice (Č=>C), Liberec, Plzeň, Praha. And I have to use array_multidimensional.

Comment: Add a few strings to your code and provide the expected result after sorting. You assume all people here know czech, and it's wrong. But if you give examples (and what you expect), even without knowing czech someone can help.

Comment: Well, it's not really about czech language, but about accented characters. Ok here is an example: I have a multidimensional array, I'm sorting it by names of the czech cities. Some czech cities are: Praha, Beroun, Plzeň, České Budějovice, Liberec. If I sort it just by plain array_multidimensional sorting, the results is: Beroun, Liberec, Plzeň, Praha, České Budějovice. I need to get here: Beroun, České Budějovice (Č=>C), Liberec, Plzeň, Praha. And I have to use array_multidimensional.

Comment: without the example it's hard to help. Add the values, add the output you expect

Comment: I edited my previous comment.

Comment: Don't add this as a comment, update your original question (and next time you should mention a user (using the @ in the comment), otherwise there is no notification

Comment: Your "solution" worked fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'cs_CZ.utf8', 'czech');
```